# using nn.Sparselinear in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

Hi I am implementing sparsely connected neural network using the following code
'This is the part of the code that has the problem'

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import sys
import os



class FeedforwardNeuralNetModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        # Linear function
        self.fc1 = nn.SparseLinear(input_dim, hidden_dim)

        # Non-linearity
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        # Linear function (readout)
        self.fc2 = nn.SparseLinear(hidden_dim, output_dim)


    def forward(self, x):

        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)

        return out
```

But I am getting this error
AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'SparseLinear'

Answer (score 1):

It worked by adding, in the libraries, this line:

from sparselinear import SparseLinear

and modifying these lines

from:

self.fc1 = nn.SparseLinear(input_dim, hidden_dim)

self.fc2 = nn.SparseLinear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

to:

self.fc1 = SparseLinear(input_dim, hidden_dim)

self.fc2 = SparseLinear(hidden_dim, output_dim)